# hive tranpose rows to columns

Tags: hive, hiveql

Need to transpose columns to rows.

[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbBYC.png)

i have pre-defined columns to be expected. if that records present ,column value to be populated as yes in the corresponding column else no by default.

set of column to be expected as follows : Col_A,Col_D,Col_X,Col_T,Col_M,Col_E

[Output Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsoQ6.png)

Let me know for any questions

Comment: please post text instead of pictures

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding. if i form a text as input data, its coming weird ( data coming in one line) which isn't easy for anybody to understand which is why posting as an image.

Comment: It would be better having one line formatting than pictures and someone will format it for you. One needs usable data example to try writing query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table transpose (Input data)

```
+--------+---------+
| col_id | col_val |
+--------+---------+
| axc    | col_x   |
| bdf    | col_f   |
| cde    | col_x   |
| yhc    | col_b   |
| idx    | col_a   |
| dft    | col_y   |
+--------+---------+
```

Hive Query to transpose col_val :

```sql
 SELECT a.col_id,IF(array_contains(collect_list(a.map_values['col_x']),'1'),'Y','N') AS col_x,
IF(array_contains(collect_list(a.map_values['col_y']),'1'),'Y','N') AS col_y,
IF(array_contains(collect_list(a.map_values['col_a']),'1'),'Y','N') AS col_a,
IF(array_contains(collect_list(a.map_values['col_b']),'1'),'Y','N') AS col_b,
IF(array_contains(collect_list(a.map_values['col_f']),'1'),'Y','N') AS col_f FROM (
       SELECT col_id,
              col_val,
              map(col_val, '1') map_values
       FROM   transpose) a GROUP BY a.col_id;
```

Result

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col_id | col_x | col_y | col_a | col_b | col_f |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| axc    | Y     | N     | N     | N     | N     |
| bdf    | N     | N     | N     | N     | Y     |
| cde    | Y     | N     | N     | N     | N     |
| dft    | N     | Y     | N     | N     | N     |
| idx    | N     | N     | Y     | N     | N     |
| yhc    | N     | N     | N     | Y     | N     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you Akash:)